# How to access a checkBox inside a repeater Header?

Tags: c#, asp.net, checkbox

I have a repeater which has a checkBox in the headerTemplate

```
<asp:Repeater ID="myRepeater" runat="Server">
  <HeaderTemplate>
    <table>
      <tr>
        <th>
          <asp:CheckBox ID="selectAllCheckBox" runat="Server" AutoPostBack="true>
                         .
                         .
                         .
```

I'm wanting to know how I can get the value of that checkBox in the code behind. Any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inside your ItemDataBound method call FindControl("checkboxID") and cast to Checkbox

```
void myRepeater_ItemDataBound(object sender, RepeaterItemEventArgs e) {
    if (e.Item.ItemType == ListItemType.Header) {
        CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)e.Item.FindControl("selectAllCheckBox");
        bool isChecked = cb.Checked;
    }
}
```

Or you could do this anytime:

```
CheckBox cb = (CheckBox)myRepeater.Controls.OfType<RepeaterItem>().Single(ri => ri.ItemType == ListItemType.Header).FindControl("selectAllCheckBox");
```

Comment: That second option doesn't seem to work. Can't find the checkBox

Comment: Sorry, the second way won't work - I'm deleting it.  If you want to grab stuff in your header or footer row, you have to use the ItemDataBound event (my first way) - see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/495597/why-is-the-footer-item-not-included-in-repeater-items